# Am trying to import FlaskForms from flask-wtf... Not able to import FlaskForms

Tags: python, forms, flask, anaconda

I am using flask 1.0.2 in Windows (Anaconda IDE).
I have installed flask-wtf 0.14 (downloaded and pasted in site packages)

I am able to import flask-wtf, but am not able to import FlaskForms.

Below is the command and error

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForms
>>> from flask_wtf import FlaskForms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'FlaskForms'
>>>
```

Can someone suggest the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to `import FlaskForm`, not `FlaskForms`.